# How do you deserialise this json from jquery booking calendar pro?

Tags: c#, deserialization, json

I am using a jquery plugin http://envato-help.dotonpaper.net/booking-calendar-pro-jquery-plugin.html for a calendar control. 
The calendar returns `JSON` as below.

```
    "YYYY-MM-DD":{"available": "", // Number of Available Items
                  "bind": 0, // Set if a day is a part of a group (0 = none; 1 = first day of a group; 2 = in the group; 3 = last day of a group)
                  "info": "", // Day informations
                  "notes": "", // Day notes
                  "price": "", // Price
                  "promo": "", // Promotional Price
                  "status": ""}, // Day status (none, available, booked, special, unavailable)
    // Another day              
    "YYYY-MM-DD":{"available": "",
                  "bind": 0,
                  "info": "",
                  "notes": "",
                  "price": "",
                  "promo": "",
                  "status": ""}
```

Im struggling to understand how to convert this into an object, because of the nesting. Shouldn't the date be a name, rather than the actual data?

I know that I can use a dictionary like this,

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.DeserializeObject(s);
```

but I would rather have a proper object. Can it be done with this JSON string?

Comment: Is it an array or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would suggest using Newtonsoft.Json instead of the pre-packaged JavaScriptSerializer, even Microsoft is nowadays using it and has discontinued further development going into the JavaScriptSerializer component as far as I know. Newtonsoft.Json is faster and easier to use. See http://james.newtonking.com/json for more information on that.

Regardless of what serializer you choose, you can apply the following things to both (maybe some class/method names are different):

I think the easiest approach here would be to declare a `Dictionary<string, DayInfo>` and try deserializing it using the `Deserialize<T>` method instead of `DeserializeObject`.

You need to define a `DayInfo` class yourself that contains all the properties that you'd like to have deserialized, potentially all of them, e.g.:

```
public class DayInfo {
    public string Available { get; set; } // would map to the "available" property in the JSON
    public int Bind { get; set; } // would map to the "bind" property in the JSON
    // ...
}
```

You need to make sure that the properties you define on `DayInfo` are of the correct type.

The deserialization should then be:

```
var dictionary = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, DayInfo>>(jsonString);
```

Once you have the JSON deserialized into `Dictionary<string, DayInfo>` you can still apply further transformations to convert into what you consider a *proper object*.

Comment: I've converted it to use the Newtonsoft.Json as you suggested. I'll add my code as any answer for anyone else who is interested, but mark yours as 'Answered'. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the resulting code thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24595932/61256) from PermaFrost.

```
public class DayInfo
{
    public string Available { get; set; }
    public int Bind { get; set; } 
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Promo { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

.... Then .....

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[HttpPost]
public void SaveCalendarData()
{
    string json = Request.Form["dopbcp_schedule"];
    Dictionary<string, DayInfo> calendarData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, DayInfo>>(json);

    // Process dictionary...
}
```

In the html/javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* Set up the calendar */
    $('#backend').DOPBackendBookingCalendarPRO({
         'SaveURL': '/Calendar/SaveCalendarData'
    });

// Code omitted....
```